# Spring MVC “redirect:/” prefix redirects with port number included

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect, nginx

I am using tomcat and nginx together to serve my web application. 
nginx listens to port 8085 and forwards requests to tomcat which is running on port 8084.

If I do a redirect like the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String test() {
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

the page gets redirected to port 8084 (Tomcat port) instead of nginx port(8085).

How can i redirect to the desired port?

Edit:
My nginx configuration is similar to this:

```
server {
    listen 8085;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    location /{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8084;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
    }
}
```

and contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:

```
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size 8m;
client_body_buffer_size 256k;
proxy_connect_timeout 120;
proxy_send_timeout 120;
proxy_read_timeout 120;
proxy_buffer_size 4k;
proxy_buffers 32 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
```

Comment: could you add your nginx configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `$server_port` instead of `$proxy_port` part in you configuration.

change this line

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
```

to

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
```

Catalina's `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect` implementation uses the `getServerPort` method to build an *absolute* redirect url (`Location` Header-Value). `getServerPort` returns the part after the `:` from the request's `Host`Header-Value which has to be *8085* in your case.

Comment: Your solution works if nginx port is 80 as you stated in your answer. But for test purposes I need this to work for other ports (such as 8085 in my question) as well.